# Is there a name for a "You benefited therefore you did it" fallacy?

Tags: logic, fallacies

When talking about conspiracies, you often hear things like

> group X benefited from event Y
>
> therefore group X must have caused event Y

I'm sure everyone knows lots of examples: 9-11, ISIS, tsunamis, etc.

Is there a name for this specific fallacy?

It's not the same as the common wisdom of "follow the money", which can be a useful *starting point* for eg. a criminal investigation; I'm talking about the case where this reasoning is used as a definitive proof, or hard evidence.

Comment: It is a form of "post hoc ergo propter hoc".  The benefit was a result, so (pursuit of) it must have been the cause.

Comment: @jobermark Beat me to it. :)

Comment: Personally, I like "lunacy."  This is so far from logical thought, I would hesitate to label it a fallacy.

Comment: On the other hand, the similar statement: "Group X benefited from event Y, therefore they're at the top of the suspect list" is perfectly logical.

Comment: Since you are interested in fallacies, I smell a lot of [straw dogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) here.  I doubt very much you could provide a real example to back up your "examples: 9-11, ISIS, tsunamis, etc." -- i.e., someone who actually literally said, "Because group X benefited from 911, they *must* have caused it."  No doubt there are people who have made absurd claims about 911, but they at least attempt to provide some evidence. If you want to refute them without being even more absurd, you refute what they have *actually* said, not twist it to suit your rebuttal.

Comment: In fact, *any* real world example of what you are talking about would be interesting to see...

Comment: @jobermark that sounds about right

Comment: @goldilocks it's not from some online source I can quote or link to, I was just curious what it would be called.

Comment: @goldilocks and before you ask, yes, I meet people in real-life that will throw out a one-liner like that and then smugly think they've won the argument

Comment: @goldilocks  The standard example is "Jews/Homosexuals/Asians are disproportionately seen among the wealthy/entertainment/banking, so they must control the economy/the system."  (It is so common historically that Jon Stewart can allude to it and get a laugh from the Left without even stating it.)

Comment: @jobermark Yes, but Steward is mocking something that does not deserve to be taken seriously -- he is attacking a straw dog on purpose.  On occasion when someone real actually does say something specific along these lines, J.S. may hold their actual words up to real scrutiny.  I.e., your "standard example" is still **not a real example**.  By real example, I meant a real person who has made real, quotable statements of this sort with a straight face.

Comment: It sounds like the line preceding my favorite line in The Departed.  Alec Baldwin asks "Cui Bono? Who benefits?".

Comment: @goldilocks  Hitler was dead serious.  The whole "Protocols of the Elders of Zion" thing is exactly this case you keep asking for.  You look at who is where in European society, imply they cannot deserve this, and accuse them of cheating.  How much more specific of an example do you need -- a specific passage of Aryan Nations' propaganda?  You can find a few in the script of "The Brotherhood" if you really, really need specificity.

Comment: I know I should die from the "Hitler Rule" at this point, but WASP anti-Semitism is the same thing, and I hear it pretty often.  So is the common conservative homophobic or racist argument that GLBT folks/Asian immigrants (see Bill O'Reilly on Jon Steward just last week) don't need protection because the visible ones already make more money than average, and they just expect too much.  I just did not want to look for text, because the whole thing is too depressing.

Comment: @jobermark I'll take your word for it WRT the protocols of Zion.  My point is that it would be very unusual for someone to commit themselves publically to this because it is so blantantly unreasonable.  I did see O'Reilly and while what he was saying about Asians is easily dissected, it's not along these lines because he did not claim they engineered anything, just that they were beneficiaries (it's actually J.S. who claimed the engineering honours for white men)...

Comment: ...As Roel points out, there are people who will say all kinds of ridiculuous things in casual conversation -- but I doubt throwing *post hoc, ergo propter hoc* will make a difference to that.  If it did, most of them probably have an elaborate causal narrative about exactly how the engineering was done (so no longer *post hoc...*).  But fair enough: I admit there are surely points in time where this is a legit fallacy.

Comment: People seldom use it alone.  In isolation it is pretty clear.  They use it to poison the well, and then before it is fully digested, they follow up with a genetic fallacy to discount other things the group is saying (like "discrimination against us actually exists").  Look at the Romney quote about the 47% of the population that is 'takers'.  It tails quickly into pity for the 'actual producers' in society, and it really is claiming that Democrats engineered a culture of dependency for their own political benefit.  That was only sort of public, but it was a fund-raiser, not a private spat.

Comment: @jobermark ...So you should turn that into a legit answer!

Comment: In science it is the old axiom, correlation is not causation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a form of "post hoc ergo propter hoc". The benefit was a result, so (pursuit of) it must have been the cause.

It often occurs as "poisoning the well" immediately before a planned "genetic fallacy" which effectively "begs the question".

Look at the situation Mitt Romney was caught in during the 2012 election cycle, where he pointed out that Democrats had created a situation where 47% of the population effectively pays no taxes, and that is not fair to those who do.

He is implying that Democrats purposefully created a culture of dependency to further their own political ambitions.  Because it benefitted them, they let the poor make unreasonable demands on the rich.  In fact, I doubt there is such a plot.  But this is not his main point, his main point is that this makes them untrustworthy and hostile to 'real taxpayers'.  But you can only believe this deduction if you accept the conspiracy theory behind the original statement.  And we have come full circle -- these folks were not doing the public's (possibly misguided) bidding, they were plotting their own ascent to power.

The Left is just as deep in this boat with attacks on "Big Pharma", "Big Oil", etc.  The implication is that these are not mere beneficiaries of a (possibly biased) system we all agreed to, but plotting conspirators.  Despite the fact that those making the decisions are obligated by the law -- the contract of fiduciary responsibility to stockholders -- to always act to maximize profit (within the law, reason, and applicable stated charters), we are expected to see their doing so as underhanded gaming.

(The same steps:  They won too big => they must have rigged the game [PHEPH].  Just like THEM to do that [poison the well].  Most of what they do is evil, and so is this game rigging [genetic attack].  Therefore hate them for rigging the game [begging the question].)

Comment: +1 for the political example - an a good answer, of course.  I'll have to remember that when my sister launches into one of her rants.

Comment: @NickR I added an offsetting, less specific, example so as not to seem biased.